# NativeScript’s WebView play JS sound

Tags: android, ios, webview, nativescript

Is there a way to play JS sound though WebView on NativeScript 3.4 or 4.0 and the sound should not stop Spotify from playing. For both iOS and Android.

**Case**
I have an JS function that plays an beep sound. And it should not stop other music app like Spotify from playing.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Just add this in the info.plist file and it will work play sound from js in a webview.

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

---

**Old:**

No it's not possible. I did use the [NativeScript WebView Interface](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-webview-interface) to communicate from JS to NativeScript to play a sound.